# My status won't update and it keep pulling from the previous status

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-remoting

Here my script, basically it refreshes service, everything is working fine until that last status check after `Start-Sleep 25`. It keeps pulling the first status that it received (I have couple check status in this script and it uses the first status instead of rechecking it).

For example, if the service is offline and it will use the first offline status that was acquired when checking for the first time and display it after the service have been turned on. Any way to show have the script recheck the status and display it instead of using the first one?

```
$services = "RTCRGS"
$SvrName = 'CORPxxxx.xxxx.xxxx'
Get-Service -ComputerName $SvrName -Name $services | % {
    Write-host "$($_.Name) on $SvrName is $($_.Status)"
    if ($_.Status -eq 'stopped') {
        Write-Host "Starting $($_.Name) in 5 sec..."
        Start-Sleep 5
        Write-Host "$($_.Name) is Starting, please wait..."
        $_.Start()
        Write-Host "Checking status of service, please wait for 25 sec..."
        Start-Sleep 20
        Write-Host "$($_.Name) on $SvrName is $($_.Status)"
    } elseif ($_.Status -eq 'running') {
        Write-Host "Restaring $($_.Name) in 5 sec..."
        Start-Sleep 5
        $_.Stop()
        Start-Sleep 5
        Write-Host "$($_.Name) is Starting, please wait..."
        $_.Start()
        Write-Host "Checking status of service, please wait for 25 sec..."
        Start-Sleep 25
        Write-Host "$($_.Name) on $SvrName is $($_.Status)"
    }
}
```

Comment: The status doesn't update dynamically. It shows the status at the time of the query. You need to re-query to get an updated status.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers Any suggestion on how I could do it? Any example would be much appreciated

Comment: Re-run `Get-Service`, of course, e.g. `Get-Service -ComputerName ... | Select-Object -Expand Status`

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers Should I add it after elseif ? or somewhere else. Sorry, I'm new to PowerShell.

Comment: You need to run that wherever you want to output the updated status.

Comment: I find it easiest in this situation to define the command then invoke it when needed: Define this at the start of your script $RetrieveServiceStatus = { (get-service -computername $SvrName -name $_.name).status} Then every time you need to check the status within your If..Then..Else structure you can use Invoke-Command  $RetrieveServiceStatus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the start-sleep 20 statement do a new get-service to refresh status