# Getting error in my script

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-remoting

I keep getting an error message stating

```
"Exception calling "Start" with "0" argument(s): "Cannot start service RTCRGS on computer 'CORPxxxxxxx.xxxx.net'."
At line:25 char:18
+          $_.Start <<<< () 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException"
```

Any suggestion on why this happens and how to fix it?

```
$services = "RTCRGS"
$SvrName = 'CORPxxxx.xxxx.xxxx'
Get-Service -ComputerName $SvrName -Name $services | % {
    Write-host "$($_.Name) on $SvrName is $($_.Status)"
    if ($_.Status -eq 'stopped') {
        Write-Host "Starting $($_.Name) in 5 sec..."
        Start-Sleep 5
        Write-Host "$($_.Name) is Starting, please wait..."
        $_.Start()
        Write-Host "Checking status of service, please wait for 25 sec..."
        Start-Sleep 20
        Write-Host "$($_.Name) on $SvrName is $($_.Status)"
    } elseif ($_.Status -eq 'running') {
        Write-Host "Restaring $($_.Name) in 5 sec..."
        Start-Sleep 5
        $_.Stop()
        Start-Sleep 5
        Write-Host "$($_.Name) is Starting, please wait..."
        $_.Start()
        Write-Host "Checking status of service, please wait for 25 sec..."
        Start-Sleep 25
        Write-Host "$($_.Name) on $SvrName is $($_.Status)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an issue with the service on the target server? i.e. can you manually stop/start it? (i.e. it may be disabled). Some services may need to be manually started a different way.

Comment: I concur.  Have you tried using `Start-Service` with the `-ComputerName` parameter?

Comment: Which `$_.Start()` line is it failing on? if it is the second one, you need to add a check and wait loop before trying to restart it. i.e. the service may still be in a "Stopping" state and would error out when trying to restart. (i.e. 5 seconds likely is not enough time for the service to fully stop)

Comment: @HAL9256 Thank you for the help, amazing suggestion on the time and loop!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the service is NOT disabled (and you have checked you can restart it manually) you might be better of with something like this

```
$services = "RTCRGS"
$SvrName = 'CORPxxxx.xxxx.xxxx'
Get-Service -ComputerName $SvrName -Name $services | ForEach-Object {
    Write-host "$($_.Name) on $SvrName is $($_.Status)"

    if (@("Stopped","StopPending","Paused","PausePending") -contains $_.Status) {
        Write-Host "Starting service $($_.Name), please wait..."
        $_.Start()
    } 
    else {
        Write-Host "Stopping service $($_.Name)..."
        $_.Stop()
        # as HAL9256 suggested, perform a loop to see if service has really stopped
        do {
            # recheck the ACTUAL status, not the status you captured before
            $newStatus = (Get-Service -ComputerName $SvrName -Name $_.Name).Status
        } while ($newStatus -ne "Stopped")
        Write-Host "$($_.Name) is Restarting, please wait..."
        $_.Start()
    }

    Write-Host "Checking status of service, please wait for 25 sec..."
    Start-Sleep 25

    # here again you should recheck the ACTUAL status, not the status you captured before
    $newStatus = (Get-Service -ComputerName $SvrName -Name $_.Name).Status
    Write-Host "$($_.Name) on $SvrName is $newStatus"
}
```

You can read the possible values for 'Status' [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontrollerstatus(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Ah.. and i see you have asked about the status [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51788419/my-status-wont-update-and-it-keep-pulling-from-the-previous-status)